# Пояснение по итераторам и генераторам python

Tags: python, итераторы, генераторы

Прошу совета/пояснения: Где лучше использовать генератор, а где итератор.

Допустим есть итератор:

```
class MyIter1:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.num > 0:
            self.num -= 1
            return self.num
        raise StopIteration
```

И цикл for:

```
for i in MyIter1(10):
    print(i)
```

В цикле у `MyIter1` вызывается метод `__next__`  и используется значение, которое он вернул.

И есть генератор:

```
def gen(num):
    for x in range(num):
        if num > 0:
            num -= 1
            yield num
```

И к нему такой же цикл for:

```
for i in gen(10):
    print(i)
```

В цикле у `gen` вызывается `next()` и используется значение, которое он вернул.

И вот вопросы:

Чем различаются эти 2 способа (просто на мой взгляд они примерно одинаковые), где лучше использовать каждый из них и в каких ситуациях они будут существенно различаться (желательно с примерами).

P.S. Я знаком с генераторами и понимаю принцип их работы, что их применяют для потоковой обработки данных, но я не до конца понимаю в чём разница, ведь это можно сделать и итератором, просто вызывая у него `__next__()` тогда, когда это требуется.

Comment: Не ломайте себе голову. Все это одно и то же. Есть концепция итерации - то есть опрос "дай следующий элемент". Итератор - объект, который знает что дать в ответ на "дай следующий элемент". Генератор - тот же итератор, который генерит элементы "на лету". А синтаксис генератора,  фунция `iter()` и yield просто генерят классы итераторов за вас. Да и функция `range()` тоже генератор. И можно  `range(10, 0, -1)` без yield

Comment: @vitidev `range` - это не генератор, это специальный объект, он умеет быстро проверять вещи типа `100_000_000 in range(100_000_000_000)`, генератор так не умеет.

Comment: @CrazyElf и что с того? выглядит как генератор, ходит как генератор, крякает как генератор... )

Comment: @vitidev, `range` не генератор. Генераторы все одноразовые. `range` - объект (`iterable`) который может породить сколько угодно итераторов/генераторов. Это происходит каждый раз когда начинается цикл `for`.

Comment: @Universal, то что вы назвали итератором, на самом деле и `iterator` и `iterable`. В случае, генератора `iterable` не создаётся. Это тонкая разница.  Например: `range` - функция, её вызов возвращает `iterable`, который в цикле порождает `iterator`. Поэтому результат вызова `range` можно использовать несколько раз в нескольких циклах. Генераторы таким свойством не обладают - они одноразовые. Функционально любую итерацию вы можете записать и так и так. Мне никогда не приходилось использовать объект-итератор. Генераторы всегда удобнее. Но если вспомнить про производительность...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за пояснение)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример использования генератора:

```
def flatten(sequence):
    for element in sequence:
        if hasattr(element, '__iter__'):
            yield from flatten(element)
        else:
            yield element

print(*flatten([1, [2], [3, [4]]]), sep=' ')
'''
1 2 3 4
```

А как бы вы реализовали это с помощью итератора?

Comment: Спасибо, я перечитал всё и понял. Вопрос снят.